# Can application running in AKS cluster talk to cluster in other cloud vendors(GCP&AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, azure-aks

We are writing a tool that can provide the health information of kubernetes cluster(in data plane) through [client library](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/)

---

This tool(Pod in a cluster within AKS) is deployed in AKS.  Tool uses this [Client library](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) to help provide health information of kubernetes cluster(in data plane) within AKS

But, there are also kubernetes clusters installed on multi vendors(GCP & AWS)

1)
How does the tool get access to kubernetes cluster running in GCP & AMS? Is this credential based access?

2)
Can tool use the same [client library](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) to get the health info of kubernetes cluster(in data plane)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, yes(1) and yes (2) the same application can get access to all of your various Kubernetes clusters for infrastructure vendors.

For Kubernetes cluster (regardless of where it is running - AKS/GCP/AWS) you can use the same k8s `client` library to access the API - the only thing that will change across providers is the `credentials` the application will use to authenticate with the server. So, same code, just different credentials. That's because it is the *SAME* API you're interacting with - the k8s API server.

Think of it this way, that from your application's perspective, there is no difference between k8s hosted on AWS/GCP or Azure. The application is concerned only with connecting to an API endpoint that belongs to the k8s cluster `api-server`. As long as you have configured the connectivity correctly in your cloud provider (right credentials, security group settings, routes etc.), the *same* code and application can talk to all the clusters very easily!

However, if you choose to utilize some of the features provided by your cloud vendor, then you will have to use the different SDKs that each vendor provides, because, naturally the APIs for AWS, GCP and Azure are different from each other and each require different code for integration. That is, if you want to query EKS or GKE or AKS for health status, instead of the Kubernetes `api-server` itself, then your code will change, but if you use the `api-server` itself, then only credentials will change.

Comment: For your point: "*As long as you have configured the connectivity correctly in your cloud provider (right credentials, security group settings, routes etc.), the same code and application can talk to all the clusters very easily!*"
Am yet to look into this aspect

Comment: We use `api-server` to get the health status

Comment: It's just as simple as allowing an incoming connection into your compute instance that is running the kubernetes API server :)

Comment: Ah, then you're fine with the present code, no need to redo anything, just get the right credentials and allow certain connections inbound to your API server.

Comment: When my tool tries to connect to kubernetes cluster `api-server`(of GCP or AWS or AKS).
Does credential(username/password) based connection suffice to connect to `api-server`? or does the `api-server` also use a certificate based communication?

Comment: Certificates are the best way to add programmatic access. Username/passwords are hard to manage. I'll suggest use certificates.

Comment: Is it symmetric key encryption where just root CA is needed, by client?

Comment: When you say credentials, did you mean certificate but not username/password?

Comment: No it's not symmetric encryption only. The client will require a key-pair where public key will have to have been signed by the root CA of the api-server. Yes, I meant that certificate is a preferred way.

Comment: Related to question, when talking to API server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73396202/error-no-kind-clientconfig-is-registered-for-version-authentication-gke-io