# Error - no kind "ClientConfig" is registered for version "authentication.gke.io/v2alpha1" in scheme "pkg/runtime/scheme.go:100"

Tags: go, kubernetes, gcloud, kubectl, google-authentication

Below is the code(with invalid kubernetes cluster URL - 10.xx.xx.xx sitting in google cloud) :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
)

func NewK8sClient(masterUrl, kubeconfigPath string) (kubernetes.Interface, error) {
    // use the current context in kubeconfig
    fmt.Println("NewK8sClient() - Invoke BuildConfigFromFlags()")
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags(masterUrl, kubeconfigPath)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // create the clientset
    return kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("main() - Invoke NewK8sClient()")
    clientSet, err := NewK8sClient("https://10.xx.xx.xx:443", "./conf.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(clientSet)
}
```

---

to recognize `kind:ClientConfig` config yaml(`./conf.yml`) for authentication:

```
kind: ClientConfig
apiVersion: authentication.gke.io/v2alpha1
spec:
  name: dev-corp
  server: https://10.x.x.x:443
  certificateAuthorityData: ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
  authentication:
  - name: oidc
    oidc:
      clientID: aaaaad3-9aa1-33c8-dd0-ddddd6b5bf5
      clientSecret: ccccccccccccccccc-
      issuerURI: https://login.microsoftonline.com/aaaa92-aab7-bbfa-cccf-ddaaaaaaaa/v2.0
      kubectlRedirectURI: http://localhost:12345/callback
      cloudConsoleRedirectURI: http://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/oidc
      scopes: offline_access,profile
      userClaim: upn
      userPrefix: '-'
      groupsClaim: groups
  preferredAuthentication: oidc
```

---

Below is the error:

```
$ go run main.go
main() - Invoke NewK8sClient()
NewK8sClient() - Invoke BuildConfigFromFlags()
error loading config file "./conf.yaml": no kind "ClientConfig" is registered for version "authentication.gke.io/v2alpha1" in scheme "pkg/runtime/scheme.go:100"
<nil>
$
```

---

Environment in which, above code is executed, has:
`kubectl oidc login --login-config ./conf.yml --cluster cluster-1`
succeeded

---

As mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl#install_plugin):

`kubectl` and other Kubernetes clients require an authentication plugin, `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin`, which uses the [Client-go Credential Plugins](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins) framework to provide authentication tokens to communicate with GKE clusters.

So, we are using `client-go` library, in the  above code: https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go

---

How to load `kind:ClientConfig` config yaml for authentication(OIDC based authentication)?

Just to add more info... `kind:Config` config yaml is working, which is certificate based authentication(not OIDC based authentication)

Comment: Have you checked this GCP document for [configuring identity service for GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/oidc#kubernetes-objects)?